# I want to get the list of VM's that doesnt have tags

Tags: azure, tags, azure-vm

I have the requirement of getting list of untagged VM's in my azure portal, There are nearly 220 VM's, how can I get the list of vm's with no tags.

There is an auto shutdown policy configured in azure and want to get list of vm's which doesn't have any tags configured.

Can someone pease help me out on this , as I am very new to azure.

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below PS script,

```
Get-AzVM | Where-Object { $_.tags.count -eq 0 }
```

[image]